# 'polls' is not a registered namespace

Tags: python, django

Im trying to get my head around this bug which I have going through the tutorial for django 1.7 (python 3.4.0)

here is mysite/urls.py -

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

and here is my polls/templates/polls/index.html -

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

polls/urls.py -

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>\d+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
)
```

My directory tree is -

```
.
└── mysite
    ├── db.sqlite3
    ├── manage.py
    ├── mysite
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   ├── settings.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   ├── urls.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   └── wsgi.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── templates
    │   │   └── admin
    │   │       └── base_site.html
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── wsgi.py
    ├── polls
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── migrations
    │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   └── __pycache__
    │   │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │       └── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── admin.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   ├── models.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   ├── urls.cpython-34.pyc
    │   │   └── views.cpython-34.pyc
    │   ├── templates
    │   │   └── polls
    │   │       ├── detail.html
    │   │       └── index.html
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── views.py
    └── urls.py
```

Iv'e already tried restarting the server and probably anything about this issue in stack overflow..

Removing "polls:" from "{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}" seems like it fixes that but i don't know if it still gives me the desired functionality

Help?

Comment: What does your `polls.urls` module look like?

Comment: Btw see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-include for reference.

Comment: Updated the question with polls.urls

Comment: Does you `polls` directory contain `__init__.py` to mark it a proper package?

Comment: Updated the question with the whole tree

Comment: Solved it, I accidentally had two urls.py files - mysite/urls.py and mysite/mysite/urls.py, I edited the top one, which is nonsesnse.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, I accidentally had two urls.py files - mysite/urls.py and mysite/mysite/urls.py, I edited the top one, which is nonsesnse.